# Is there a way to exclude merged commits from a branch in Git?

Tags: git, github, version-control

How do I remove commit already merged to master on a branch?

I had a master branch and a branch off of master called "A" with 2 new commits. Then off of branch "A" I made another branch "B" with a new commit.

I've merged branch "A" with master, but now I have 3 commits on branch "B".

I want branch "B" to have only the commits that haven't been merged with master. I don't want it to have the commits from branch "A" anymore.

Tried rebase. I still have the three commits, two of which I don't want to show on branch B.

Answer (score 0):

```
git rebase --onto master B~1 B
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I remove commit already merged to master on a branch?

One way is to do an interactive rebase and then drop the commits that you don't want. The command is: `rebase -I <commit>` where *commit* is some commit earlier in the history than the ones you want to drop. Git will then open an editor that lets you manipulate the commits after *commit* -- you can keep them as they are, change the commit message, change their order, squash them into another commit, drop them, or any of several other actions.

However, if you're planning to eventually merge B back into master, then you'll actually want the commits in branch B because they're part of the common history between B and master. As long as they occur before the new commit in B, git will see them as already being in master and won't add them to master again.